# Nsubstitute set return value with Generic Repository

Tags: unit-testing, generics, nsubstitute

I have a generic repository for MongoDB.

This is my Get method:

```
public IList<TEntity> Get<TEntity>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null) where TEntity : class, new()
{
    var collection = GetCollection<TEntity>();

    var query = Query<TEntity>.Where(filter);
    var entity = collection.FindAs<TEntity>(query).ToList();

    return entity;
}
```

When I try to mock it, I get an error:

`IList<Login>` (where Login is my business object) does not contain any a definition for `ReturnsForAnyArgs`.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckIfUserNameExits_IfUserNameDoesNotExist_ReturnFalse()
{
    Login login = null;
    Task<IList<Login>> logl = null;
    // _mongoDAL.Get<Arg.Any<Login>()>(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>).ReturnsForAnyArgs
    //_mongoDAL.When(x => x.Get<Login>(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Login, bool>>>())).ReturnsForAnyArgs(logl);
    _mongoDAL.Get<Login>(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Login, bool>>>()).ReturnsForAnyArgs(logl);
}
```

Any suggestions on how to mock it, so that I can set the return value I want in my unit test?

Comment: "...does not contain any a definition for ReturnsForAnyArgs" -- this sounds like you are missing a `using NSubstitute;`?

Comment: Yes, i have it included. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by you passing the wrong type to your `ReturnsForAnyArgs` call.  This behaviour is the same, if you are calling `Returns`, or `ReturnsForAnyArgs`.

Your `Get` method is defined as returning `IList<TEntity>`.  In your initial question you are returning `logl`, which is of type `Task<IList<Login>>` (notice the `Task` wrapping your `IList`).  In your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35391876/592182) however, you are instead passing `loginList`, which is a `List<T>`, which implements `IList<T>` hence your code compiles.  So, as an alternate, you could have used:

```
_mongoDAL.Get<Login>(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Login, bool>>>())
         .ReturnsForAnyArgs(loginList);
```

The compilation error you get initially is a bit cryptic.  The full error message is:

> error CS1928: 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnsForAnyArgs' and the best extension method overload 'NSubstitute.SubstituteExtensions.ReturnsForAnyArgs(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, T, params T[])' has some invalid arguments

The first half of the error message *looks* like it's pointing to a missing extension method.  However, in reality the problem is that it's failing to match to any of the overloaded methods and so it's picking the closest and showing you how it doesn't match.

Typically you'll get a second error that will help to indicate that this is your problem.  Something like this:

> error CS1929: Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>>'

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

```cs
var loginList = new List<Login>();
_mongoDAL.Get<Login>(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Login, bool>>>()).Returns(loginList);
```

Don't know why with just Returns, it works.